# AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT weird behaviour

Tags: mysql, aes

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('test', 'mysecret'), 'mysecret')
```

returns 74657374, which `UNHEX()` can't do anything with. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"74657374" is "test" in ASCII, displayed in hexadecimals. You are feeding UNHEX the wrong information, or you may need some way of transforming the resulting bytes into text.

Comment: Great, so it is working. How do I convert it to something human readable?

Comment: There are a few bug reports on this problem, but I think the column type is lost as there isn't any. I would recommend to create a sample where you actually store/retrieve results from the database. It probably reverts to a byte array type now. It doesn't convert to hex, it's just the bytes, which are displayed in hex.